# Поиск длины отрезка на плоскости оптимизированный по объему исходного кода

Tags: c++

Входные данные

Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит координаты концов отрезка в формате X1 Y1 X2 Y2 . Все координаты – целые числа, не превышающие 1000 по абсолютной величине.
Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите длину отрезка с точностью 10-5.

Максимум чего я смог достичь 113 символов, спасибо [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) :

```
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
main(){int a,b,c,d;scanf("%i%i%i%i",&a,&b,&c,&d);printf("%.5f",hypot(c-a,d-b));}
```

Подскажите, что ещё можно сократить? Как сделать код ещё короче?Есть информация, что можно дойти до 91

Comment: А где тут файлы?

Comment: @maestro ввод такого формата из стандартного потока допустим, я это не уточнил

Comment: А функцию [`hypot()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) использовать не хотите?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо большое! Обновил вопрос)

Comment: сделайте библиотеку и тогда просто `int main(){f();}`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, решение в 1 файле должно быть

Comment: Выбросить `.5` - по умолчанию выводится 6 знаков, для заказанной точности хватает. Вам надо именно C, не С++? вроде там ввод-вывод короче.

Comment: Кажется, этому вопросу будет лучше на код-гольфе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

либа `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` содержит в себе кучу стандартных либ - 91 символ

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
main(){int a,b,c,d;std::cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;printf("%f",hypot(c-a,d-b));}
```

спасибо Harry,Mikhailo